# Exporting image with visual-paradigm api throws nullpointerexception

Tags: visual-paradigm

I’m trying to export diagram as image with this plugin https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/openapi/export-diagram-img-plugin/.
But when i want to export, i got an null pointer exception in vp log (see below).
This issue appears with this plugin provided by VP or in my own plugin.

VP (15.2) is running on Windows 10. With trial license and local repository.

Error occurs with this method:

```java
ApplicationManager.instance().getModelConvertionManager().exportDiagramAsImage(diagram, file, option);
```

I expect the creation of image on my disk but I got the following exception:

```
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] java.lang.NullPointerException
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at v.avj.g.a(:195)
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at v.bea.p.a(:900)
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at v.bea.p.exportDiagramAsImage(:743)
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at v.bea.p.exportDiagramAsImage(:727)
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at v.bea.p.exportDiagramAsImage(:715)
[2019/06/12 09:25:31] [message] at com.vp.plugin.sample.exportimage.actions.ExportImageActionControl.performAction(ExportImageActionControl.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem actually was already being fixed in the latest patch build. Please follow the details below to update the software to latest patch build (20190530cj or later) to get it fixed.

https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/articles/update-to-latest-patch.jsp
* Please make sure you have pressed the **Update to latest patch** button on the left hand side of the dialog right after launching the update program